# Mutate or equivalent to add multiple columns returned from a function in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to figure out how to add multiple columns returned from a function which takes one or multiple columns from the same data frame as input - basically, I want mutate but with the option to left_join() a data frame. I can do this with either left_join() or cbind() but there must be a better way.

The actual code I am using is taking columns for revenues, costs, capital expenditures and other information and calculating tax and other fiscal policy output.  Because they are interdependent, I need to do this all in one function (I can't do it one variable at a time) and I really don't want to call the same function multiple times and then mutate by columns (although I could do that too).

Here's a really simple example (contrived) of what I want to do:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(nycflights13)
#small data frame of new years day flights from JFK
df1<-flights %>% filter(year==2013,month==1,day==1,origin=="JFK")  
#test function
arr_gate_time<-function(time){
  dep<-time
  gate<-time-hours(1)
  check_in<-time-hours(2)
  data.frame(gate,check_in)
}
```

What I want to be able to do is, within mutate, do something like this:

```
df_test_2<- df1 %>% mutate(SOMETHING=arr_gate_time(dep_time))
```

But, the closest I can get is

```
df_test<-arr_gate_time(df1$time_hour) 
df_test_2<-cbind(df1,df_test)
```

I'm sure there's an easy implementation of dplyr to do this, but I can't figure out the right command structure.

Thanks!

Comment: By `SOMETHING` I take it you mean more like the `sk-learn` / `pandas` style of `SOMETHING1, SOMETHING2 =` right?

Comment: Yes, or some similar syntax - I want it to append the two columns to the data frame.

Comment: What about just `df_test_2 <- df1 %>% cbind(arr_gate_time(.$time_hour))`? Is mutate any better?

Comment: @Ryan, it might be just that simple! I didn't know that I could cbind across a pipe.

Comment: You can pipe into any function!

Comment: @Ryan You should make that an answer

Comment: Seems to do what I want.  Thanks, @Ryan

Answer (score 3):

`tidyverse` solution

```
library(tidyverse)
df_test_2 <- df1 %>% bind_cols(arr_gate_time(.$time_hour))
```

Base R (modifies original data frame)

```
df1[c('gate', 'check_in')] <- arr_gate_time(df1$time_hour)
```

`data.table` (modifies original data frame)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)
df1[, c('gate', 'check_in') := arr_gate_time(time_hour)]
```

Comment: Thanks, @Ryan.  Do you know offhand if tidyverse vs Base R solution would be necessarily faster? I'll test both with my real code as I work it out unless it's obvious.

Comment: I believe the `tidyverse` solution makes a copy of `df1` even if you're assigning it back to `df1`, so the Base approach should be faster in this case.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure. You could do some tests with the `microbenchmark` package. I would do a time comparison for this data and post it, but this data is to small for it to matter.

Comment: The tidyverse version of `cbind` is `bind_cols`